# Github Actions - node.js CI

Tags: angular, github, yaml, github-actions, schema.yml

I am having problems with the node.js template. It seems to be looking for the package.json in the wrong directory? And I can't find anything online for documentation on how to handle this.

I am trying to upload my entire repo, which contains a client, server and design folders. The client is an angular 9 project where the package.json is residing.

On action build I get the following ENOT error:

**npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/runner/work/Real-Reviews/Real-Reviews/package.json'**

Can anyone help?

See below references for action set up.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Presumably that action looks in the root directory for the package file by default, how is it supposed to know you intended it to look in `client/`?

Comment: Yeah I understand that. I'm more wondering how can you control the github action and tell it to search in the right place? instead of looking in the root it needs to look in the client, and run the ng build in the client as it won't work in root outside an angular env.

Comment: I don't know, did you read the docs for that action to see if it offers that configuration?

Comment: I have no idea. That's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: Well I would recommend looking at https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsrun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @jonrsharpe mentioned in the comments you need to change the [working directory](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#defaultsrun) you're running in.

```yaml
steps:
  run: npm install
    shell: bash
    working-directory: client
  run: npm run build --if--present
    shell: bash
    working-directory: client
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I've almost got everything working, except for now when it gets to the run: npm test. It is giving me "Chrome failed 2 times (cannot start)" in ghub action. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd guess you're running some e2e tests in your `npm test` call? There could be a number of reasons it doesn't work on the runner. Perhaps chrome isn't installed, perhaps the webdriver isn't, perhaps it is but you're not running headless mode? Really no way to tell from where I'm sitting